# Extract data dumps from .sql file

Tags: sql, database, backup, data-dump

I've got an .sql file, it's an database backup from four years ago. This .sql file is filled with table creations but also data dumps. Because I actually don't need and want the data I'm looking for an way to extract all the data dumps from the .sql file. So that I'm only restoring the tables architecture.

I **think** the .sql file was generated by cPanel backup service.

Is there some automated way of doing this? I can't do it by hand because the .sql file has an enormous amount of lines.

Comment: Any problem with importing it then performing a DROP on the tables?

Comment: you mean DELETE FROM, he still wants the tables just not their content

Comment: Currently I'm using an shared hosting account, wich doesn't even allow me to execute an .sql file of this size. I don't want to also find an workaround for that and after that delete the data again.

Comment: I think you're going to have to import the data dump locally and then export just the structure to another SQL dump file using `mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p thedatabase > dumpfile.sql`

Comment: Of course that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Boyd: Import the dump file locally using

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p thedatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

Then export just the structure using

```
mysqldump -u username -p --no-data thedatabase > newdumpfile.sql
```